# WiFi Packets Delayed on Real iPhone but not Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios-simulator

I'm working on an app that connects to a device on the same local WiFi network. The device takes measurements and streams the data to the iPhone. The iPhone plots it in real time.

The problem I've run into is the iPhone delays the packets by up to 200ms every half second or so. This causes noticeable stutter in the UI that I'd like to eliminate.

I started debugging the issue by placing signposts in the code when packet is received.

Looking at the profiler, you can easily see the gaps in data.
[image]

Zooming in on the space after a gap, you can see a burst of packets received.
[image]

I've checked and it isn't dropping any packets. It is simply delaying them from my app.

The weird thing is this isn't an issue on the simulator or with the Android version of the app so I know it isn't an issue with the device or the WiFi network.

Here is the same code running on the simulator showing a much more even distribution of packets.
[image]

Has anyone experienced anything like this? Is this just some kind of battery saving limitation of the iPhone hardware? Is there anyway to ensure a more timely delivery of the data to my application?

I tried rewriting the connection using [SwiftNIO](https://github.com/apple/swift-nio) and ended up with the same results. I've also tried changing the `serviceClass` parameter of the connection to all the possibilities with no change.

Here is the relevant connection code.

```
    private func udpReceive() {
        if udpConnection?.state == .ready {
            udpConnection?.receive(minimumIncompleteLength: 1, maximumLength: Int(Hangboard.shared.BufferSize), completion: { content, contentContext, isComplete, error in
                os_signpost(
                    .begin,
                    log: log,
                    name: "udpReceive",
                    signpostID: signpostID
                )
                Task {
                    if let content = content {
                        let _ = await asyncResult(for: Hangboard.shared.udpDataReceivedNative(data: content.toKotlinByteArray(), offset: 0, length: Int32(content.count)))
                    }
                    os_signpost(
                        .end,
                        log: log,
                        name: "udpReceive",
                        signpostID: signpostID
                    )
                    self.udpReceive()
                }
            })
        } else {
            disconnect(hadError: true)
        }
    }
   
    private func startUdpListener(port: NWEndpoint.Port) {
        let params = NWParameters.udp
        params.allowFastOpen = true
        params.serviceClass = .responsiveData
        
        let listener = try? NWListener(using: params, on: port)
        self.udpListener = listener
        listener?.newConnectionLimit = 1
        listener?.newConnectionHandler = { connection in
            connection.parameters.serviceClass = .responsiveData
            self.startUdpConnection(connection: connection)
        }
        listener?.start(queue: .global(qos: .userInteractive))
    }
    
    private func startUdpConnection(connection: NWConnection) {
        self.udpConnection = connection
        connection.stateUpdateHandler = { state in
            switch state {
            case .ready:
                self.udpReceive()
            case .failed(let error):
                print("Connection error! \(error.localizedDescription)")
                self.disconnect(hadError: true)
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        connection.start(queue: .global(qos: .userInteractive))
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the reason for this was because I was still running a Bonjour search in the background.

Disabling the search when connecting and restarting it on disconnect removed the latency issues.

Apple's tech support mentioned this can be a problem when `includePeerToPeer` is enabled on a connection.